# update matched element in yii2 using $elemMatch

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

any body know how to update particular matched element like below select query

```
$account = $query->from('user')
            ->where([
                'email_account' => [
                    '$elemMatch' => [
                        'email' => 'abcd@gmail.com'
                    ],
                ],
            ])
            ->andWhere(['_id' => $userId])
            ->all();
```

if you know update query for the element so let me know pls so i can update below object of Yii

```
"email_account" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "abcd",
        "email" : "abcd@gmail.com",
        "password" : "abcd",
    },
    {
        "name" : "test",
        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "password" : "test",           
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any of the update operators, say for instance **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** to update the `name` field, use it together with the **[`$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to identify the position of the matched array item in the query and then manipulate it.

Something like the following example using MongoDB without Active Record and 
calling the database directly:

```
$criteria = ['_id' => $userId, 'email_account.email' => 'abcd@gmail.com' ];
$modifier = [
    '$set' => [
        'email_account.$.name' => 'Jane Doe'
    ]
];
Yii::app()->mongodb->getCollection('collectionName')->update($criteria, $modifier);
```